# My button is not displayed in Android Studio

Tags: java, button, android-studio, onclick

I am trying to do my very first application on Android Studio, so I began with an Hello World that worked perfectly, then I tried to add a button with a simple onClick function which changes the button's name.
I want the button "New Button" to change into "Clicked" once clicked.

Here is my main class :

```
package com.example.mcaulet.premierprojet;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PremiereActivite extends Activity {

    public void buttonOnClick(View v){
    Button button=(Button) v;
        ((Button) v).setText("Clicked");
    }
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView texte = new TextView(this);

        texte.setText("Ceci est mon premier projet !");

        setContentView(texte);

    }

}
```

This only shows "Ceci est mon premier projet !" but not my button, I want to know why.

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** you need something like this :

```
public class PremiereActivite extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button v = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonid);

     v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

         Toast.makeText(PremiereActivite.this, "Ceci est mon premier projet !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();         }
 });


}

}
```

Comment: Do I have to delete the function buttonOnClick? and what is buttonID?

Comment: don't forget to add Button with id "buttonid" to your xml file

Comment: AndroidAlarmService is a mistake replace it with "PremiereActivite" and buttonid you have to create it in a xml

Comment: Yes I have seen your edit,I did everything you said but when I launch the emulator it says "your project has stopped" or something like that..

Comment: In the event log? I have this : 14:27:55 IndexOutOfBoundsException: chars sequence.length:20, start:91, end:111: chars sequence.length:20, start:91, end:111

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71882/discussion-between-maxime-and-mounir-elfassi).